# Postgresql: how to calculate the percentage correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

With this very simple query I obtain the count(total) and genre of movies
from my db.

```
select genre,count(*) from titles group by genre order by count desc;
     genre       | count 
-----------------+-------
 Drama           |   529
 Comic           |   393
 Martial arts    |   276
 History         |   269
 Action          |   237
```

My question is: how to get a percentage?
I want something like this

```
select ??????;
     genre       | percentage 
-----------------+-------
 Drama           |   30%
 Comic           |   20%
 Martial arts    |   20%
 History         |   15%
 Action          |   11%
 Other           |   4%
```

I have tried a lot of codes taken from gogle and stackexchange before asking, as you can see from this psql history
but all fail with error or very strange results.

```
SELECT
    title,
    ROUND( AVG( genre ), 2 ) percentage
FROM
    titles
INNER JOIN genre
        USING(id_genre)
GROUP BY
    title
ORDER BY
    genre DESC;


select title, round ( AVG( genre ), 2 ) percentage from titles;


SELECT round((count(genre) *100)::numeric / NULLIF(count(*), 0), 2) AS percentage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select genre,
       count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
from titles
group by genre
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: Is ok, thanks. I had only had some "corrections" to remove / truncate decimals and add the %

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gordon for the correct answer, using this string I obtain a perfect result(except for 0% results which are the 0.0001... rounded by round function, but is not a problem)

```
select genre, count(*) as total, round(count(*) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over ()) || ' %' as percent from titles group by genre order by total desc;

     genre       | total  | percent 
-----------------+--------+-------------
 Drama           |    529 | 17 %
 Comic           |    393 | 13 %
 Martial arts    |    276 | 9 %
 History         |    269 | 9 %
 Action          |    237 | 8 %
```

...